# Adding bulk records in posgres with sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have one table called 'Table' which has one to many relations with another Table called column
Si that each Table have many column
Now i want to insert bulk records of Table with array of column.i have search alot but haven't find how to insert bulk records into foriegn key table as well
Example
I got 10 Table objects in array format with 5 column objects in array in each Table row. I want to insert with one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `bulkCreate` method can't insert records along with associated models' records. You should use `create` for each record using `include` option and indicating an array of associated records. Don't forget to use an explicit transaction to add all records as an atomic operation.
See [Creating with associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html)

```js
return Product.create({
  title: 'Chair',
  user: {
    firstName: 'Mick',
    lastName: 'Broadstone',
    addresses: [{
      type: 'home',
      line1: '100 Main St.',
      city: 'Austin',
      state: 'TX',
      zip: '78704'
    }]
  }
}, {
  include: [{
    association: Product.User,
    include: [ User.Addresses ]
  }]
});
```

Comment: For example if i want to insert 20 Tables records then it will be very heavy task and will interact 20 times with database . Any other way some how i can do this less hit

Comment: Ok, you can try to bulk create main records (then in PostgreSQL it can be one INSERT only) but you still will need to create all child records separately.